# Is it possible to autowire configuration of one spring project configuration to other spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, autowired

I have to spring services. In one I am configuring javaMailSender as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class EmailConfiguration {

    @Value("${mail.host}")
    String host;
    @Value("${mail.username}")
    String username;
    @Value("${mail.password}")
    String password;
    @Value("${mail.smtp.auth}")
    String auth;
    @Value("${mail.smtp.port}")
    String port;
    @Value("${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}")
    String enable;
    @Value("${mail.smtp.fallback}")
    String fallback;
    @Value("${mail.smtp.ssl.enable}")
    String ssl;

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender()
    {
        JavaMailSenderImpl msender=new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        Properties mailProperties=new Properties();
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth",auth);
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable",ssl);
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.fallback",fallback);
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",enable);
        msender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
        msender.setHost(host);
        msender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
        msender.setUsername(username);
        msender.setPassword(password);
        return msender;
    }
}
```

now in other spring service which is basically a spring bacth job, I am autowiring the dependency as follows:

```
public class NotificationItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<NotificationInstance, NotificationInstance> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class.getName());
    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    @Autowired
    Connection connection;
    @Autowired
    Queue queue;

    @Override
    public NotificationInstance process(NotificationInstance notificationInstance)
    {
        if(notificationInstance !=null)
        {
            NotificationChannel channelAdaptor;

            NotificationChannel channel = NotificationChannelFactory.getSingleton().getChannelInstance(NotificationChannelType.valueOf(notificationInstance.getTargetType().toUpperCase()));
            notificationInstance.setRetries(notificationInstance.getRetries()+1);
            logger.info("Trying to send notification for id {}",notificationInstance.getNotificationId());
            Boolean status=channel.send(notificationInstance, javaMailSender);
            updateStatus(notificationInstance, status);
            return notificationInstance;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    public void updateStatus(NotificationInstance notificationInstance, Boolean status)
    {
        if(status)
            notificationInstance.setStatus(NotificationStatus.SENT.toString());
        else if (notificationInstance.getRetries() < 5)
            notificationInstance.setStatus(NotificationStatus.QUEUED.toString());
        else
            notificationInstance.setStatus(NotificationStatus.FAILED.toString());
    }
}
```

plus I have included the dependency of first service in second service pom.xml.
After running the first service which is running fine, when I start the second service I am getting error as follows:

framework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

**Solution**
I tried with both @Import("") and @ComponentScan(""). I am not getting any compile time error but at runtime I am getting NullPointerException for JavaMailSender object.

Answer (score 2):

You could also import the `EmailConfiguration` class from the configuration class of your spring batch application.

```
@Import(EmailConfiguration.class)
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to "tell" your context that you want add this bean to your application context.

can be done by scanning the package that this class is located  (`EmailConfiguration`).

1. xml config - add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.conf" />` to your xml configuration.
2. java config -  add `@ComponentScan("com.example.conf")` to one of your configuration classes.